# Use tapply function in dataframe in R

Tags: r, tapply

Here is my dataframe df:

> ```
> x y
> ```
>
> 1 1 1
>    2 1 2
>    3 2 3

And I get the result:

> 2
>   3

with the code:

> tapply(df$y, df$x, sum)

But I expect to get

> 3
>   3

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you edit this to display the entire output, as Justin pointed out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the correct answer, just reading it wrong.

look at the whole output:

```
> tapply(df$y, df$x, sum)
1 2 
3 3
```

Your groups are 1 and 2 and the values are 3 and 3.  Is horizontal.  You can see this if you try `tapply` in the other direction

```
> tapply(df$x, df$y, sum)
1 2 3 
1 1 2
```